# Who came to Troy?

Tags: trojan-war, iliad, homer

Near the end of Book II of the Iliad, Homer says that if he had nine tongues, he could not list all those that came. He then lists as many as he can. Do other authors add to the list?

Answer (score 2):

Apollodorus also has a [Catalogue of Ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogue_of_Ships) at Troy in the Epitome of the Bibliotheca ([E.3.11 ff.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0022%3Atext%3DEpitome%3Abook%3DE%3Achapter%3D3%3Asection%3D11))

---

You may also be interested in this paper: *[A Programmatic Function of the Iliadic Catalogue of Ships](http://classics.ufl.edu/files/05_HomericContext_Marks_TCSV.pdf)*